# How to pause game and display new layer in corona

Tags: coronasdk, onpause, corona-storyboard

I am new to corona.
I want to ask that how can I make pause functionality in any game.

For example I want to make a pause button that pauses game and display some buttons with a resume button.

Is there any way to do this?
With story-board or any other functions or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it with storyboard to give you an idea implementing pause button if you are using animation,physics,timer,transition etc.. that needs to be pause you must call their specific pause function and if you want to display resume and some other button you can make an overlay of that scene and then hide it so when the user presses the pause button you can show it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide, now I can pause the game, but now one more thing I am facing, just do guide me that how can I Restart the same class, I hope you understanding my point.

For e.g., if I pause the game during gameplay, and I want to restart the game, that is the same class in which I am, then how can I do this?

2. If I put the Main Menu button, and call   storyboard.gotoScene("MainMenu")
Then it goes there fine, but when I come back to the gameplay, then it has the same state from where I left. All the objects and variables does not restart, that is I actually want?
Any help?

Comment: well no problem. i got the same issue when i try to retry my game and find out that you can't call the same storyboard so i make a dummy storyboard and point the retry there and after that the dummy storyboard will call the game storyboard so its like this when you press retry button (gamestoryboard)->(dummystoryboard)->(gamestoryboard) hope this helps

Comment: well, I did the same, on dummyScene's createScene, I got the values of optional params, and on enterScene I execute your idea, means gotoScene("gamePlay", options), but following issues takes place

1. All variables and state of game is still remain
2. gamePlay scene appears twice and disappear (gamePlay appears, then disappears then appears then disappears)

where I lack to do it in right way?

Comment: 1.on your dummyScene when it enters try removing the gameScene to recreate the whole scene don't purged it remove it 
2. as for the number 2 problem it's difficult to point out where exactly the problem is coming since i don't know the codes

Comment: I debugged it, and I noticed that it goes in createScene of gamePlay, first time, but when I come from dummyScene, it not goes to createScene, but directly goes to enterScene.

Comment: yes because as for storyboard in corona if you do not remove the Scene and go to another scene it will not go to create scene but rather go to enter scene when you go back that's why if you want to call again create scene you must remove the scene when you go to another scene

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31985/discussion-between-devfar-and-hamza-hasan)